# pull vs push deployment

Tags: php, deployment

Apparently there are two strategies used for deployment of web application. Please correct me if I am wrong.

### Pull Deployment

I have my own build, deploy scripts. I use git as vcs. Deploy script will pull the code from git repository and build script will configure the app.

**Pros**

- Easy installation.
- Better scalability (as my ssh key resides in server, it can contact our vcs server). So even our application server grows we don't have to bother.

### cons

- Security issue as ssh key in every application server.

### Push Deployment

I had used this method with my old project, where I used rsync to push the code. I push a copy from the local machine, but still we had used vcs.

**Pros**

- Full control, flexibility as I don't have to push the code to vcs.

**cons**

- Not better scalability.

I have checked some tools, which offering both strategies. (http://capifony.org/)

### Questions

- How do you guys handle this for a large scale project? (built with php).
- Is there any better strategy?
- Which is better in between these two?
- What if there are many application servers under load balancer? will push make sense here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of having your SSH keys on the servers, why not use SSH agent forwarding to pull the code? E.g., https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding

Comment: hmm interesting, But Users must SSH in to deploy, automated deploy processes can't be used!

Answer (score 2):

> Full control, flexibility as I don't have to push the code to vcs

This to me is not a good thing. You will have *more* control using a VCS than without. I generally create a production branch alongside a development and feature branches, that way the production server only ever pulls down code that I've deliberately put into the production branch.

Furthermore, if you ever run into a problem where your production code suddenly breaks, if you're using a VCS you should be able to roll back to a working version while you figure out what's wrong with your code. This, to me, is one of the most beneficial aspects of using a Pull Deployment.

If you use a continuous integration tool like Jenkins, you can periodically check for changes on a specific branch in your VCS, and have Jenkins automatically pull and build your project for you, without anyone ever needing to log in to the production server themselves. This makes deployment as easy as updating your code in the repository.

> security issue as ssh key in every application server

Depending on where your code is hosted, you might be able to set up deployment-only keys. This is how Bitbucket is set up, so our production servers can only *pull* code, not push. Furthermore, if one of these servers is compromised, we can easily revoke the access on our repository to that specific key.

Comment: I forgot to say, I had used vcs for my old project (deployment to a production server is from my deployment machine). I still have a flexibility to revert back to old revision. (eg: I checkout release branch, and push the code with rsync).

Comment: +1, I agree with the CI tools suggestion, I have some experience with jenkins & phing! I posted this question to make sure I don't miss some better strategies! thank you for answering :)

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing other solutions as well, then. Is it just you working on the project, or are there other developers? If it's just you, I wonder if there's much of a benefit to using something other than plain old rsync, especially if you're already keeping things version controlled.

Comment: In fact, there are many, but only two people takes care of deployment. We are planning to move our production server to amazon cloud (with Elastic Load Balancing service). We would like to see all the strategies before we proceed. As computing servers shutdown/launch automatically based on load (hardware scalability), we want some good system to handle all the issues.